# Mac video editors - Where are they?

Tags: macos, video-editing

For the life of me I can't find a video editor for Mac OS X that can edit the major formats. I switched recently. I used to use TMPGEnc Xpress 4 on Windows. It accepts any format and I can cut and trim all I want and export into a combined file or separate files.

I couldn't find anything like that on Mac since I switched in February 2012. Please help me find one, I am drowning in video files that need editing and all my HDDs are full.

PS: I'm talking frame accurate visual timeline editing, not like Handbrake, where you have to enter the number of frames or seconds. Handbrake also cannot combine parts.

Comment: Do you mean you can't find any free or open source software?

Answer (score 2):

[AviDemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) has a Mac version, and handles multiple file types.

[MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/) has a Mac version and handles a few file types, but is purported to be a bit basic.

[ZS4](http://www.zs4.net/) has a Mac version, but is a different kind of editor.  Might be worth a look, considering it's free.

[HyperEngine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hyperengine/) AV is a free Mac editing tool.

Of course, you could always install Windows on a part of your hard drive using Bootcamp, and then use TMPGEnc again... or any other Windows editing tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried 2 of those but I will try the other 2. Its sad to see there is nothing equivalent on the Mac. I switched blindly thinking Mac has to have a similar or better video editing app that accepts all the major formats.